# Netgear router/powerline adapter assigning wrong IP address via DHCP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, powerline-networking

I've got a problem with my router and powerline adapter, for some reason my router and powerline adapter assign odd IP addresses to me network devices, but not all of them  and not all the time:/ You see normally my IP addresses start with 192.168.0.x and I've got a reservation table so all my devices get the same address each time they log in , but my router and powerline adapter just gave my Dad's iPad an address that was something like 169.254.x.y cant remember the other two digits, What could the reason be for this?

The router is a Netgear DG834GT and the powerline adapter is an AV 200, model is XAVN2001

Comment: Are the router and the powerline adapter two separate devices or one?

Comment: the router is seperate from the powerline, eg the powerline takes internet from the router transmits it through the powerline of my house to an emitting station that i plug into the wall and then emits a wireless signal with with its own SSID(and ip address on the network) but the router as its default gateway, so essentially its a fancy range booster :P

Answer (score 4):

**169.254.0.0/16** is the [IPv4 link-local](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) address range (also called in Windows "Automatic Priviate IP Address" or APIPA). These addresses are *not* assigned by DHCP but automatically generated by the device. If you get a IPv4LL address, it usually means that your iPad cannot find the DHCP server for some reason.

If this happens with *all* devices, it might mean that your network is too unreliable. (You could test packet loss using `ping` or `mtr`.)

Comment: na it doesnt happen with all my devices just some. What i meant to say was that i have an address reservation list on my router so that each router gets assigned the IP adrress that the reservation tells it  to, like my laptop is 192.168.0.21 normally, eg now, but earlier on it could 169.254.x.y and when i did ipconfig beside ipv4 it had "automated", so does that mean it couldnt get an IP address so it just gave a automatic one?

Comment: @andrew: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: so why would it not be able to get an IP address? Would the 'preferred' address have to be taken by another device?

Comment: @andrew: No, if the preferred address was taken your device would simply request another address from DHCP. If you get a 169.254 address, it almost always means there was no DHCP response *at all*. I can suggest starting Wireshark on one of the problematic computers and repeatedly renewing the DHCP lease (`ipconfig /renew` or `dhcpcd -n <interface>`), to take a look at the actual requests being sent. Also, if the router runs Linux, you can use `tshark` or `tcpdump` to see if those requests *reach* the router.

Comment: Alright cool, ill give it a shot. Its a bit disturbing that their was no response from the dhcp at all :/ what can the cause of that be? heavy network traffic?

Comment: One cause would be if the DHCP server was out of addresses. Another would be if the device wasn't really connected to the network (or was connected to a device that wasn't). Unfortunately, some devices not designed as bridges (like cheap wireless routers) don't properly bridge DHCP requests to wired devices.

Answer (score 2):

Your router did not give you that 169.254.x.x address, your iPad did. It is because you are not really connecting to your network.

You either have a physical hardware problem, driver-not-correct issue, or a network configuration issue. Most likely a network configuration issue.

Make sure the SSID and password are typed correctly. Both are case sensitive. Make sure that you have the same type of encryption.

Also, check to make sure that if your wireless router has an access list, you add the iPad's MAC address to the list of accepted devices. It is under your wireless setting>Wireless Station Access List. If it has "Turn Access Control On" checked, you must add the MAC address to that list.

Comment: These addresses are not Windows-specific (the question mentioned an iPad).

Comment: grawity, fixed, but the answer stays the same.

Comment: Yeah, i thought that - mentioned that in the reply further down. But if it was driver not correct issue it wouldnt be a sporadic issue, it would be a consistent issue. Like as of just now, its back on the internet with the DHCP assigning it the correct address based on its mac address whereas before it was getting assigned the automatic one(169 etc).
It did however have trouble connecting to the network once i told it to "forget" it. My xbox360 had the same issue, the day before, but as of now is working again, not changing any settings anywhere.. :/ im aware they arent specific, just example

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely sure that DHCP can't traverse the Access Point → powerline → router. I have the same issue. Only fix was to set up DHCP on the AP (router) and it would work with two different networks, e.g. `192.168.1.x` at internet router and `192.168.0.x` at Wireless Access Point.

But that sucks too, as the two networks won't talk to each other for file sharing and the like.

I just ended up grabbing a WiFi extender instead of using powerline adapters.

Answer (score -2):

I was having same problem, was being assigned a 169.254 IP address, way off from my 192.168 private network.

I was however connecting my Netgear Powerline adapters to a powerstrip. As soon as I plugged both my Netgear Powerline adapters directly into the wall outlet, all was resolved and I was now getting the right IP from my DHCP server.

Comment: Why are you spamming sqldatabasesolutions?

Comment: Hmmm, that URL made me trigger a spam flag, and vote to delete, but I guess the answer could be useful to future visitors after all...

Comment: No signatures please! I'd add that the 169 address suggests you arn't getting a  ip address, and most plowerline devices have manuals that tell you not to use a powerstrip